# Outlook rule to delete emails older than stipulated number of days

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, office365, rules

While setting mail rules, I want to be able to set them and forget them. But, I have an issue with one particular rule where I am using a `before` datespan rule.

[image]

I have `Before:` ticked and specified a date so that if the email was received before that date, it is old and must be deleted.

That's fine, but with a set and forget mindset, I want to stipulate that if the email was received more than 28 days ago, rather than a fixed date, I want it to be deleted.

Is that possible?

I have noticed [Outlook Rule - Move mail that is READ and Older than X days](https://superuser.com/q/267609/581166) but this is for moving emails older than x days, and there is a workaround in the answers but I want to delete.

[How to delete a large block of emails in outlook 2016 / outlook 365](https://superuser.com/q/1163873/581166) provides a server side sweep in the answer rather than a rule, and so I had a look at that and it provides a fixed 10 days.  I can't set it to 28 days.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To create an auto-archiving policy that deletes older emails automatically in Outlook,
do the following for each folder you want to clean automatically:

- In Outlook, right-click on the folder and select Properties
- Select the AutoArchive tab
- Select "Archive this folder using these settings"
- In Clean out items older than, enter the desired amount of days/months/years
- Select "Permanently delete old items"
- Click OK to save and close the dialog.

[image]

For more information with screenshots see the article
[How to automatically remove older emails from Exchange and Outlook](https://support.exclaimer.com/hc/en-gb/articles/360004540491-How-to-automatically-remove-older-emails-from-Exchange-and-Outlook) .

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately my System Administrator was kind enough to disable the "AutoArchive" feature for me. However, I did notice as an alternative one could go to File -> Tools -> Mailbox Cleanup... and specify the details:

[image]

But unfortunately this requires a manual step with a few clicks.